# How to properly get child component instance in Angular unit test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test with karma in Angular and i am struggling with weird problem. I am trying to test output cancel of `app-source-roll-history-form` which is inside `source-roll-history.dialog.ts`. To achive this i need instance of child component. When I am trying to get it, parent component instance is returned insted of child component instance.

**source-roll-history-dialog.html**

```
  <ng-template #newRollContent>
    <app-source-roll-history-form
      (save)="assignNewRoll$.next($event)"
      (cancel)="newAssignmentForm = false">
    </app-source-roll-history-form>
  </ng-template>
```

**source-roll-history-dialog.spec.ts**

```
  it('should show/hide form to assign new roll', () => {
  ...
    const instance = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-source-roll-history-form')).componentInstance;
    console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-source-roll-history-form')));
    console.log(instance);
  });
```

**console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-source-roll-history-form')));** gave me debug element like this:

`<app-source-roll-history-form _ngcontent-a-c295=""></app-source-roll-history-form>`

so that is fine. But when I am trying to get instance of this component:

**fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-source-roll-history-form')).componentInstance**

I am getting instance of parent:

```
SourceRollsHistoryDialogComponent{actions$: Actions{_subscribe: observer => { ... }}, toasterService: ToasterService{toastrService: ToastrService{overlay: ...,
```

Comment: I see the app-source-roll-history-form component is inside an ng-template with the newRollContent template reference variable. Isn't this used for a if / else ? maybe you just didn't mock correctly the data in the unit test so that app-source-roll-history-form is rendered

Comment: I was trying to move it outside ng-template and still the same so it is not the case, but it is inside matDialog maybe some isssue with angular Material?

Comment: If the component is rendered inside matDialog, the async aspect may be the cause. Maybe you should try to "catch" the component using a fixture.whenStable or something like that (that would wait for the component to be rendered in the dialog) if animations are involved for rendering the component in the dialog

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to test? Tests are more stable if you expect things based on the natural interfaces of a component (inputs, outputs, the user interface, the backend API), instead of checking internals. If you use a different approach, you probably do not need access to the component instance.

Comment: @slim I wouuld like to test inside parent component (source-roll-history-dialog) if after child component (app-source-roll-history-form) emit output cancel - newAssignmentForm variable is false, so form should be hided. So i need instance of app-source-roll-history-form to sp on his output.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer does not explain how to get the component instance of the child, but it offers other approaches to solve the problem behind.

In the question, the component instance of the child component is needed to trigger an output event on the child. This can be done in different ways:

1. Use the user interface to trigger the cancel event, i.e. do whatever the user would have to do to trigger this event. (Probably this means clicking on a cancel button somewhere? This would be my preferred solution.)

Or if you do not want to interact with the child component (e.g. because the setup for it is too complicated):

2. Use a mocking library like [ngMocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/) to mock the child component and to [emit an event from the mocked child](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockComponent#advanced-example). This also saves you from having to declare or provide dependencies of the child component in the TestBed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the child component is included in the `declarations` section of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. I had the same issue and that's what solved it.